# Tool to compare elasticsearch index into data base records to ascertain inconsistent state

Tags: elasticsearch

> I Want to know whether any tool available for comparing database entries into elastcisearch index to find the mismatch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to check for existing entries or do you (also) want to compare the docs against the table rows?

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this with the [Scrutineer](https://github.com/Aconex/scrutineer) tool, which provides support for comparing data stored in Elasticsearch against a source of truth, usually relational database.

After running this tool, you'll get a report of:

- records in the source of truth and not in ES (missed create)
- records in ES and not in the source of truth (missed delete)
- records in ES and the source of truth which are out of synch (missed update)

Basically, this will give you an exact overview of the de-/synchronization state of the two data stores you're comparing (ES + DB).

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is another interesting blog article on the subject: [Elasticsearch: Verifying Data Integrity with External Data Stores](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-verifying-data-integrity-with-external-data-stores)

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is yet another interesting blog article on the subject: [How to keep Elasticsearch synchronized with a relational database using Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-keep-elasticsearch-synchronized-with-a-relational-database-using-logstash)

Answer (score 1):

I believe not, this has the potential to be a very taxing operation. However if you have used a unique `PK` from your database as the `_id` for the documents in elasticsearch then you could use the following command whilst iterating through records -

```
curl -XHEAD -i 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1'
```

This will return an appropriate response as to whether the document exists or not. Storing all `_id`'s which don't exist and placing these into ElasticSearch, within your own bespoke script or application.

If this is not the case the complexity of the problem significantly rise as do the implications to the cluster.

Comment: 'thanks but already we are doing the same method which u mentioned but i anticipate whether any automation tool is available  '