# Compare IDs between two indices in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two indices in an elasticsearch cluster, containing what ought to be the same data in two slightly different formats. However, the number of records are different. The IDs of each document should be the same. Is there a way to extract a list of what IDs are present in one index but not the other?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034722/tool-to-compare-elasticsearch-index-into-data-base-records-to-ascertain-inconsis/35643728#35643728 I'm also working on a tool called [examiner](https://github.com/consulthys/examiner) but I'm a bit behind on the development.

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way to have scrutineer look at two elasticsearch indices rather than a database?

Answer (score 6):

If your two indices have the same type where these documents are stored, you can use something like this:

```
GET index1,index2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_uid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_uid"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_indices": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "_index"
          }
        },
        "values_bucket_filter_by_index_count": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "count_indices"
            },
            "script": "params.count < 2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query above works in 5.x. If your ID is a field inside a document, that's even better to test.

Comment: Say I have abundant amount of documents in both indices, then how could I partially process the result? Is there anything like offsets or paginations available for me ? or any work around solution?

Comment: For ES7 I just needed to change "_uid" to "_id"

Comment: I am using ES7 and this query does not seem to work while fetching docs present in both the indices. I tried changing 'params.count < 2' to 'params.count == 2' but no luck. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: @noob_nerd if there are different docs between the 2 indices, their id will be listed in the aggregation section. If there is no difference, it will look like following: ` "aggregations" : {
    "group_by_uid" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 8,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 5976,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this, Scrutineer (https://github.com/Aconex/scrutineer/) provides this sort of ability if you follow convention of ID & Version concepts within Elasticsearch.