# How to validate elastic search data with sql data after migration from sql to elastic search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, data-migration, database-testing

Anyone who have worked on elastic search. need input as mentioned in subject. I have one requirement in which sql data is migrated to elastic Search now there is ton of data so I can not check each and every field manually. So what is best way to test migrated data with sql.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034722/tool-to-compare-elasticsearch-index-into-data-base-records-to-ascertain-inconsis/35643728#35643728

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement 2 scripts which will result exactly the same output from mysql and elasticsearch. Make sure, formatting, ordering matches. At the end you should be able to diff the files or do md5sum on them to compare.

Comment: Hi Tamas can you suggest which technology would be better for comparing it

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I have done it using JAVA and JUnit.