# How can I compare two Elasticsearch indices with Kibana or Elastic syntax?

Tags: elasticsearch, compare, kibana

I have two indices in Elasticsearch. Both "should" have the same data and be identical (so they have the same columns and entries). But I know there some errors in one of the indices. Which means the columns still are equal, but the data can differ. How can I now make a Visualiation or Dashboard to show which entries are only in one index, and missing in another. Or which rows differ in their values between index 1 and index 2.

Thanks for any tips you can get :)

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034722/tool-to-compare-elasticsearch-index-into-data-base-records-to-ascertain-inconsis/35643728#35643728

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But Scrutineer compares an index with a SQL database. I would like to compare two indices. And Scrutineer depends on that you have a version column in your tables, which we dont have.

Comment: True, I found Scrutineer quite handy but missed a few features so I started creating a [handy tool](https://github.com/consulthys/examiner) that does exactly what you want, but haven't finished it yet. Stay tuned...

Comment: Sounds nice. But you should consider commiting a bit more alpha code than just your readme ;) Maybe someone will join you and help coding ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's barely alpha quality, and it's been quite dormant lately, but I still expect to publish something before the summer.

Comment: In any case, it's not too complicated to do it yourself. Basically, you issue a scroll request on both indices sorted by `_uid` and then you compare the records one by one as explained in my post above.

Comment: OK I understand what you mean (Scroll API Elastic). I was hoping that Kibana could solve this for me without any programming and problems like "What is source, what is target?" and "What if some exist in index a and some in index b?". Thanks for the feedback. I will try to find something. And if not, maybe write some myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do it programmatically. Its not really a feature in Elastic or Kibana and never will be. You have to use scrolling.