# Verifying data consistency between Oracle and Elasticsearch

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch, bigdata

I have an Oracle database with 80 million records. These have been migrated to elasticsearch and there is a continuous sync running that will keep the data updated in elasticsearch whenever data is added/changed in the Oracle database. I have two questions regarding this.

1. How to verify if all 80 million records have been indexed in ES? This might be fairly easy running count
2. How to verify the data consistency on a periodic basis, say each week to ensure that both data sources, Oracle and ES are in sync?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034722/tool-to-compare-elasticsearch-index-into-data-base-records-to-ascertain-inconsis/35643728#35643728

Comment: This seems like a good tool. It came across a some while back. My indexes have nested objects so this might not work well for the nested objects verification.

Comment: ideally you would only need to verify the id exists in ES and that the version is the same as in your Oracle DB. Of course this means that you need to have a version column in your DB that you increment everytime you modify your record. You should 't have to verify field by field