# Compare fields values of two document type values under one index

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, logstash

I have two mysql tables containing thousands of rows in each table. I have index all records into elasticsearch using logstash jdbc plugin.

The Idea is to compare difference between two tables using Elasticsearch in fast manner. Faster than SQL.

I have index called elasticdata and two documents type table1 and table2.

I have to compare each column1 of table1 document type with all rows of table2 document type. If difference is found print the value.

How can it be achieved in elastic search?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034722/tool-to-compare-elasticsearch-index-into-data-base-records-to-ascertain-inconsis/35643728#35643728

Comment: Thanks @Val, I will check it out.